# Android apps not working on a real device

Tags: android

My app is running on virtual device but when i install it on samsung galaxy s3 device ,the app starts normaly, when i click a button to navigate to another layout it showing black screen and then shut down.
Please anybody give me a reason or solution for this problem.
Regards Florida

Comment: paste your logcat error

Comment: app is working in emulator ,the problem is in real device ..

Comment: use "adb logcat > log.txt" command from the console when trying to run the app on the device. Share the logcat here. It will have some information about the crash.

Comment: hey now faild to install apk on device... i will share logcat

Answer (score 0):

I asume your real device has a different version than your simulator and your app is not running with the android version of your real device.

Comment: and what can i do in this case? app must fit for all s3 device. thnx for ur answer and sorry for my english

Comment: you have to debugg it. try to run it on a simulator with the version of your real device

Answer (score 0):

Set your device to enable logging and you will be able to see the stacktrace when it crashes.

A common cause of the problem you're seeing is resources and layouts set for the wrong density or screen size. It will work OK on the emulator but not the real device. You can try to replicate this on the emulator by setting it up to match the S3's screen size and density.

Comment: the app is created for tablet, i create a layout-sw360dp folder to match the S3's screen size.the programm has two activity, first activity its ok and second is not working